# If x has Poisson distribution with parameter $λ,$ how to find MLE and UMVE of $g(λ)=e^λ (1+λ)$

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance

Given: A Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, how to find MLE and UMVE of $g(\lambda)=e^{\lambda}(1+\lambda)$. I was trying to use the invariance property of MLE and then Lehmann-Scheffe's and Rao-Blackwell theorems. But I am not sure if I am taking the right route. Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I edited the question to use latex to improve the rendering/markup. I also added a self-study tag, for more on this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: Yes, you are on the right path. Please share some of your work on the problem. Refer to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial for typesetting math.

Comment: There's no guarantee that any unbiased estimator exists; hence there may be no UMVUE. And equivariance (often incorrectly called invariance) of MLEs handles this right away if you know the MLE of $\lambda. \qquad$

Comment: What is the probability that for example $X_1\le 1$?  What is the expected value of an indicator function of an event?

Comment: I apologize for not being able to share my piece of work. This is my first time using StackExchange and I still need to learn how to interact with the groups. But, Thank you all, I think I figured it out. Yes, as Jarle Tufto indicated, I realized that the given parameter is P(X<=1) which enabled me to define an indicator function conditioned on the sufficient and complete statistic. The empirical illustration given by Geoffrey Johnson is fantastic. Thank you all for your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not give anything away, I'll just make some plots I wish someone made for me when I first studied this.

Let $X_1,...,X_n \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$.  For demonstration purposes let's say that our sample size is $n=50$ and unbeknownst to us the true fixed $\lambda$ is $3$.  The histogram below shows the sampling distribution of $\hat{\lambda}_{MLE}=\bar{X}$ based on 10,000 Monte Carlo simulations.  The mean of these 10,000 Monte Carlo samples is 3.003.  Since the maximum likelihood estimator is unbiased and a function of the complete sufficient statistic it is also the UMVUE for $\lambda$.

[image]

You are correct that based on the invariance property, $\hat{g}(\lambda)_{MLE}=g(\hat{\lambda}_{MLE})$.  Below is the histogram for the sampling distribution of this estimator over the same 10,000 Monte Carlo simulations.

[image]

The unknown fixed true $g(\lambda)$ is $g(3)=e^3(1+3)=80.3$, while our Monte Carlo mean is 84.3.  The maximum likelihood estimator of $g(\lambda)$ is a function of the complete sufficient statistic, but it is not unbiased so the MLE is not the UMVUE.  It looks like you'll have to find a suitable transformation of the MLE to make it unbiased.